# bigquery tables usage monitoring (frequency, bytes, etc)

Tags: google-bigquery

To reduce cost, I decided to delete bigquery tables which are not been queried within the past few months.
How I can check/monitor the usage of 20 bigquery tables in 2 different datasets?
Who queried? bytes queried?etc

Comment: did below my answer helped

Comment: Hi Bihang, your query gives metadata of a specific dataset and table. I was thinking of using wildcards or similar thing.

Comment: Hi Sana, you should be achieve it with subquery with information_schema.tables where table_name like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if this query helps

The query accepts dataset and table you want to monitor.

```
  SELECT start_time, total_bytes_processed,total_slot_ms,referencedObjects,referencedObjects.table_id,referencedObjects.dataset_id
  FROM `myproject.region-australia-southeast2`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS , UNNEST ( referenced_tables ) as referencedObjects
  WHERE referencedObjects.dataset_id = 'zz_DataSet' and referencedObjects.table_id = 'tblOne'
```

The output of above query shows below results. There are other columns which you add too.

[image]

The same query can be put as scheduled query with results stored in destination table which can be analysed over time.

Hope this helps